# How can I reuse this script without duplicating it multiple times? (Font-resizing relative to div-size script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

I found this code on the net and its VERY special to me.... BUT, i need it to be just a little bit more special...

This code doesnt work on multiple div's. I need to duplicate the code to make it work and change the class-name fmor newswrap to newsrap2 and so on. That will result in ALOT of code for a magazinesite like mine.

Does someone know what do do with this code to make it work on multiple divs?

PS, i got like 15 of these in my header.php at the moment

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var originalFontSize = 11.8;
    var sectionWidth = $('#newswrap8').width();

    $('#newswrap8 span').each(function(){
        var spanWidth = $(this).width();
        var newFontSize = (sectionWidth/spanWidth) * originalFontSize;
        $(this).css({"font-size" : newFontSize, "line-height" : newFontSize/0.9 + "px"});
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML-code I use

```
<div style="width:300px;">
<h3 id="newswrap8" style="margin:0px; font-size:12px;">
<span>
<a href="http://www.thelink.no">This is the page title</a>
</span>
</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you used classes instead of IDs?

Comment: Just tried it, but didnt work. The problem is that it atapts the width of the fiorst div used in the following divs. So I have to duplicate the script and rename it #newswrap1, #newswrap2, newswrap3... etc etc...

Comment: How about you show the rest of your code or better yet, a jsFiddle?

Comment: I have updated the post with some HTML code

Comment: update again with some divs i use. Now the 100% code is there

Comment: @Demilio where is `span` in your html?

Comment: sorry, missing... updateing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to test without html-markup, but idea is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var originalFontSize = 11.8;
    $('[id^="newswrap"]').each(function(){
        var elm = $(this),
            sectionWidth = elm.width();

        elm.find('span').each(function(){
            var spanWidth = $(this).width();
            var newFontSize = (sectionWidth/spanWidth) * originalFontSize;
            $(this).css({"font-size" : newFontSize, "line-height" : newFontSize/0.9 + "px"});
        });
    });
});
```